# How to fix ConnectionAbortedError in simple Tkinter websocket chat?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter, connection

I am writing a simple chat using the Tkinter library and sockets.

[image]

When I connect for the first time to the server. The server processes incoming messages and they are displayed in the chat. I am trying to implement a Disconnect button that closes the window and closes the connection. I need the ability to reconnect by a client. However, an error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
  File "user\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "\server_.py", line 16, in listen_users send_to_users(data)
  File "\server_.py", line 10, in send_to_users user.send(data)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]
```

I have implemented a closing in a disconnect()
Client code:

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter as tkn

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
message = []

def connect_to_server():
    host = adress_text.get()
    port = 49094
    sock.connect((host, port))
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        message.append(data.decode("utf-16"))
        message_text.delete(1.0, tkn.END)
        message_text.insert(1.0, '\n'.join(message))

def send_message():
    temp_mes = name_text.get() + " : " + entry_message.get()
    temp_mes = temp_mes.encode("utf-16")
    cur_mes = temp_mes
    entry_message.delete(0, tkn.END)
    sock.send(cur_mes)

root = tkn.Tk()

connecting = threading.Thread(target = connect_to_server)

def disconnect():
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    sock.close()
    root.destroy()

adress_text = tkn.Entry(root, width = 20)
adress_text.insert(1, 'localhost')
adress_text.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
name_text = tkn.Entry(root, width = 20)
name_text.insert(1, 'name')
name_text.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
conn_button = tkn.Button(root, text='Connect', command=connecting.start)
conn_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

disconn_button = tkn.Button(root, text='Disconnect', command=disconnect)
disconn_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

Server code:

```
import socket
import threading

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
users = []

def send_to_users(data):
    for user in users:
        user.send(data)

def listen_users(user):
    while True:
        data = user.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode("utf-16"))
        send_to_users(data)

def run_server(host, port):
    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen(2)
    while True:
        usr_sock, addr = server.accept()
        print(addr)
        users.append(usr_sock)
        listen_acc_user = threading.Thread(
            target = listen_users,
            args = (usr_sock,)
        )
        listen_acc_user.start()
```

Comment: Accessing `tkinter` from multiple threads isn't ideal. It can cause `tkinter` to crash without giving you an error traceback. Also once the client disconnects you never remove it from your `users` list. So the server keeps trying to send the data to it even though the connection has been closed. I think that that might be causing the problem